# read from file and print output to a file

Tags: c

I know this is how you read from a file. I also want to print my output to the same name of the file plus ".txt". So if my file is called "text" I want to print it to a file called "text.txt".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[1])
{
    FILE* Data2;
    Data2 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (Data2 == NULL)
    {
       printf("ERROR");
       exit(100);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Would it be something like this? Is it better to use "a" or "w" in the fopen? I want to write to it several times.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[1])
{
    FILE* Data2;
    FILE* Data3;
    Data2 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    Data3 = fopen(argv[1].txt, "a");
    if (Data2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR");
        exit(100);
    }
    fprintf(Data3, "\n Print something \n");
    fprintf(Data3, "\n Print something \n");
    fprintf(Data3, "\n Print something \n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to build the output filename yourself, e.g. using `snprintf`.

Comment: `if(Data2 == NULL) { perror(argv[1]); return EXIT_FAILURE; }`  Because errors belong on stderr and should state why the failure happened.

Answer (score 2):

`argv[1]` is a string. The `.txt` syntax doesn't mean appending `".txt"` to it.

However, you can do that by creating a new buffer with enough size (computed using `strlen`) and pasting both strings in there

```
char *fname = calloc(strlen(argv[1]) + 5, sizeof(fname[0])); /* +5 to have space for .txt and terminator */
strcpy(fname, argv[1]);
strcat(fname, ".txt");
Data3 = fopen(fname, "a");
```

Or, you could use `asprintf` if you can and want to use GNU extensions instead of POSIX standard:

```
char *fname = NULL;
asprintf(&fname, "%s.txt", argv[1]);
Data3 = fopen(fname, "a");
```

Now, regarding the opening of the file, it is important concerning the moment you issue the `fopen` call: if you pass in `"a"` then the contents before the opening of the file will remain there. If you pass in `"w"` then said contents will be removed. In both cases you are able to write multiple things into the file.

Comment: Would this have worked? `char *fname = calloc(strlen(argv[1]) + 5); /* +5 to have space for .txt and terminator */`? I don't understand why you have to include `sizeof(fname[0])`. I am bad with calloc and malloc.

Comment: `sizeof(name[0])` means `sizeof char`. `calloc` receives 2 arguments: the number of elements and the size of a single element.